# Parsing mathmatical functions

Tags: ruby, parsing, calculator

I have finally finished a Ruby calculator project, which is [not based on eval](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/80699/simple-calculator-using-eval). Instead it parses input char by char. The project is [hosted on GitHub](https://github.com/user689/math_expression).

However, I find a specific part of the program very annoying since whenever I have to add something I have to rewrite a portion of it again.

```
def trig
  case @look
  when 'c'
    match_all('cos')
    case @look
    when 'h'
      match_all('h(')
      value = cosh(calculate)
    when '('
      match('(')
      value = cos(calculate)
    else
      expected('cos() or cosh()')
    end
  when 's'
    match('s')
    if @look == 'q'
      match_all('qrt(')
      value = sqrt(calculate)
    else
      match_all('in')
      case @look
      when 'h'
        match_all('h(')
        value = sinh(calculate)
      when '('
        match('(')
        value = sin(calculate)
      else
        expected('sin() or sinh()')
      end
    end
  when 'r'
    match_all('root')
    base = get_number
    match('(')
    value = calculate ** (1.0/base)
  when 't'
    match_all('tan')
    case @look
    when 'h'
      match_all('h(')
      value = tanh(calculate)
    when '('
      match('(')
      value = tan(calculate)
    else
      expected('tan() or tanh()')
    end
  when 'l'
    match('l')
    case @look
    when 'n'
      match_all('n(')
      value = log(calculate)
    when 'o'
      match_all('og')
      if digit? @look
        base = get_number
      elsif @look == "("
        base = 10
      else
        expected("integer or ( ")
      end
      match('(')
      value = log(calculate, base)
    else
      expected('ln() or log()')
    end
  when 'e'
    match_all('exp(')
    value = exp(calculate)
  when 'a'
    match_all('arc')
    case @look
    when 'c'
      match_all('cos')
      case @look
      when 'h'
        match_all('h(')
        value = acosh(calculate)
      when '('
        match('(')
        value = acos(calculate)
      else
        expected('arccos() or arccosh()')
      end
    when 's'
      match_all('sin')
      case @look
      when 'h'
        match_all('h(')
        value = asinh(calculate)
      when '('
        match('(')
        value = asin(calculate)
      else
        expected('arcsin() or arcsinh()')
      end
    when 't'
      match_all('tan')
      case @look
      when 'h'
        match_all('h(')
        value = atanh(calculate)
      when '('
        match('(')
        value = atan(calculate)
      else
        expected('arctan() or arctanh()')
      end
    end
  else
    raise InvalidInput, "unexpected input: \"#{@look}\""
  end
  match(')')
  value
end
```

The `@look` variable will contain the next character. The `match_all` function will simply match the input character by character. For example, it would match `c` and if it works it continues to match `o` and so on, but if it doesn't it will output an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a toy program to illustrate the separation of user input collection from the string matching that determines which calc to use, as we discussed in the comments.  Note that the class `NamedCalculations` has no knowledge of IO with the user.  All the IO is encapsulated in `CmdLineCalculator`.

When I find a match, I just evaluate it with the argument pi.  In your real application, you'd need to do further process to gather the user's input for the argument.

Also note how if we decide we want to change which calculations we support (one of the most likely changes for the application), it becomes a 1 line change, and the user input processing code doesn't need to be touched.

```
class NamedCalculations

  # a hash of named calcs
  # eg, {cos: Math.method(:cos), sin: Math.method(:sin) }
  def initialize(calc_definitions)
    @calc_definitions = calc_definitions
    @calc_names = @calc_definitions.keys.map(&:to_s)
  end

  def method_for(calc_name)
    calc_name = calc_name.to_sym
    raise "Invalid Calculation Name" unless @calc_definitions.key? calc_name
    @calc_definitions[calc_name]
  end

  def exact_match?(input)
    @calc_names.any? {|name| input == name}
  end

  def partial_match?(input)
    @calc_names.any? {|name| name.include? input}
  end

end


class CmdLineCalculator

  def initialize(named_calcs)
    @named_calcs = named_calcs
    @input = ''
  end

  def start
    begin
      system("stty raw -echo")
      collect_user_input while not calc_complete?
      show_answer
    ensure
      system("stty -raw echo")
    end
  end

  private

  def collect_user_input
    @input += next_input_char
    validate_input
    echo_last_char
  end

  def validate_input
    raise "Invalid Calculation" unless @named_calcs.partial_match? @input
  end

  def next_input_char
    STDIN.getc
  end

  def echo_last_char
    STDOUT.putc @input[-1]
  end

  def calc_complete?
    @named_calcs.exact_match? @input
  end

  def show_answer
    selected_method = @named_calcs.method_for(@input)
    value_at_pi = selected_method.call(Math::PI)
    STDOUT.puts "\nThe #{@input}(pi) = #{value_at_pi}" 
  end

end

my_calcs = {cos: Math.method(:cos), sin: Math.method(:sin) }
client = CmdLineCalculator.new(NamedCalculations.new(my_calcs))
client.start
```

Answer (score 1):

Should sqrt, exp, etc. be in your Trig function? This seems to break the S in [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)). I would abstract out your trig function and write something like:

```
def trig(input, val)
  case input
  when "sinh" return sinh(val)
  when "sin" return sin(val)
  when "cosh" return cosh(val)
  ... // cos and tans
  end
end
```

You were right to be concerned about repeating similar pieces of code. That's something that should be avoided at all times. Coding is about being concise and minimal.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I don't know the next character . For example,  if I find an s I don't know if it is sin or sqrt

Comment: @Mhmd, How do you not know the next character?  Does `match_all` collect user input 1 character at a time?  Can you explain why it works this way?

Comment: @jonah yes it does that, I did this based on the "let's build a compiler" book and then added some functionality.

Comment: @Mhmd, In that case the first thing you want to do is to separate the logic for matching a string to a computuation (sin, cos, etc getting mapped to their matching methods) from the user input collection.  You should have one method that is collecting user input, and after each charcter is typed, it should check if there is a match yet.  Does that make sense.  You have the matching method responsible for collecting input.  But the two things are totally separate.  The matching method should know nothing about input collection.

Comment: @Jonah thanks could you write this as an answer.

Comment: @Mhmd, sure, but what happens 1) if the user types something that doesn't match any calculation? 2) after the user types the open paren... eg, I type "cos(" -- now what happens?  does it now collect the function's arguments? Basically, it would be easier to help with a full answer if I knew the spec of the program itself.

Comment: @Jonah for 1) it will just raise an error, 2) after someone types `cos(` it will now evaluate the input see above `value = cos(calculate)` where `calculate` is a separate function. If you want I have linked above the github repo of the code. However, I think you can type an answer based on the current info, it doesn't have to be a full one.

Comment: @Jonah Thanks so much for helping him out. Mhmd: Maybe you should simply wait for 4 characters and then use a function like above; as that will be the minimum number you would need to differentiate between options. It would cost you no time as you would have to wait for at least 4 chars to reach a leaf of your possibility tree.